# How do you call non static methods from static Main if Main is the starting point

Tags: c#

I am new to C# so I hope I am asking this correctly.

I created a new C# project and in it is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Consol.Write(myFirstInt());
}
```

I created a method:

```
public int myFirstInt()
{
    return 5;
}
```

That is called from the Main. I get that I can't call `myFirstInt()` because it is not static. However, if Main is the starting point for the program and always has to be static, how do you call non static methods?

Comment: You need to create an instance of class containing this method with [`new` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes).

Comment: It doesn't matter if where you call it is a static method or not, an instance member (property, variable, method) needs an instance of the object which contains it, while a static one does not, just the "path" (class.member). You should read more about static classes, as it's something crucial for any developer to fully understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have to create a new instance of the class you're running your code in.
Say your code looks like this:

```cs
public class YourProgram {
    public int myFirstInt(){
        return 5;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args){ 
        // ...
    }
}
```

You'd have to create a new instance of the `YourProgram` class like so:

```cs
public class YourProgram {
    public int myFirstInt(){
        return 5;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args){ 
        var yourProgram = new YourProgram();
        Console.Write(yourProgram.myFirstInt());
    }
}
```

---

Side note: You made a typo in your code. You wrote `Consol.Write` which sould be `Console.Write`. I corrected it in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you declared the myFirstInt method in the Program class you just have to do

```
var program = new Program();
Console.Write(program.myFirstInt());
```

although i think you just need to change myFirstInt to static

Comment: This would be a weird thing to do, as the `Program` class is created automatically and typically used as if it was static. This is fine just for fun, but I would not mix this class with other classes I need to create.

Comment: Of course, I also think you would not create a method myFirstInt which returns 5, but the question is about why the compiler throws an error.